# Fresh install of COD: Anonymous users get "Access denied" on homepage

Tags: users

### Problem

I created a clean VM & installed [COD](http://usecod.org). Unfortunately, when people aren't logged in they see:
[image: error]

How should I go about diagnosing further and/or resolving this issue?

### Things tried

- I thought this might be because the first conference wasn't published but the published flag was set, and I ticked the 'Promoted to front page' option.
- That did not resolve the issue, so I created a basic page and applied the same options. No change to the homepage.
- The homepage was set to `node/1` so I changed it to no extension so that it could use the default homepage. No change.
- UPDATE: Ticked *Grant content access* and *Grant own content access* for anonymous users in admin/people/permissions
- UPDATE: Tried to use the rebuild option (/admin/reports/status/rebuild) to no avail

Comment: Check the permissions for "access content" - do the right roles have that enabled? If so, check what content access module you have installed (if any), and how they're configured

Comment: For Content Access - these were unticked. I presume the "and modify" bit has less control than it suggests?
Grant content access: View and modify content access for any nodes
anonymous user
Grant own content access: View and modify content access for own nodes

Comment: @Clive - I ticked the two options (in admin/people/permissions), logged out, no joy

Comment: Oh so you actually have the "Content Access" module installed and enabled? That's probably the problem, that module doesn't exist on a fresh install of Drupal (where I've never seen the issue you're describing before). Whatever installation profile you've used has probably messed something up, contacting the developer would probably be the best move

Answer (score 0):

The permission required is `View published content`.

It turns out the content access module has **a lot** of different permissions that can be assigned to roles and this one is not selected by default for anonymous users.

This is a really easy permission to miss. It sits deep within `nodes` permissions and if you use the search facility for words like view or access you won't get it in the search result. Heck, if you search `View published content` it isn't returned.

Comment: For next time, [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fpa) makes administering perms a bit easier